# Finding the cycle sets of an LCG

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, congruence

My LCG has the form:

$$S_0 = k$$
$$S_{n+1} = S_n \times a + 1 \pmod m$$

Each choice of $k$ generates a different sequence but in some cases a sequence may just be a cyclic shift of another. In this case we say the two sequences are equivalent. This equivalence partitions the generator outputs into disjoint subsets, or *cycle sets*.

How many cycle sets are there for a given $a$ and $m$, and how many elements are in each one? Can I also find a representative element for each set? It does not seem practical to find the answer for large $m$ by a brute force search.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Classic reference for this: Donald Knuth's [TAoCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming), Volume 2, 3.2.1

Comment: @fgrieu: yes, but he's asking to go into further depth than what Knuth goes into; Knuth only talks about the necessary/sufficient conditions for the cycle to be maximal; what do the cycles look like when they're not maximal; e.g. when $a-1$ and $m$ are relatively prime?